# Existe alguma função na api do google maps para fazer itenerários fixos?

Tags: android, google-maps

Eu estou a trabalhar numa aplicação android e gostaria de saber se existe alguma forma de criar rotas no google maps fixas e depois usa-las para saber o caminho mais rápido para um certo destino? Como por exemplo fazer linhas de autocarros.

Agradecia a vossa ajuda, Obrigado